# How can I change title of android studio that is visible when switching apps on macos from folder name to project name?

Tags: android-studio

I moved my project files to project subfolder so I can put other stuff on upper level like some artworks etc to commit to git too, without having it messed with project files.
Now when I switch between various open android studio projects windows, I see there just title of that parent folder, that is named "project", but I would like to see there my project name, not folder name. Is there some android studio setting to change this behaviour ?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

In your `settings.gradle` add line `rootProject.name = "some-desired-name"` and this will be visible when switching apps on macOS, I believe it's called mission control, otherwise Android Studio pick folder name as project name and that was my issue.

Background: I used this before, but later commented it out, because I didn't see why it would be useful for me, now I see.